# A TSpeedButton gets stuck in the down appearance 

Tags: delphi, button

I use a TSpeedButton with property `Flat` set. When I press it and it generates an exception it remains in the pressed state. The first image  of the image below is before pressing the button and the second image during the press and, when excepting, remaining in that position.

[image]

Two events are used, OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp. The code for the eventhandlers is:

```
procedure TVector_Choice.Button_Down (Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   FStart_X  := X;
   FStart_Y  := Y;
   FSelected := True;
end; // MouseDown //

procedure TVector_Choice.Button_Up (Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   if Assigned (FOnSelect) and FSelected then
   begin
      FOnSelect (Sender);
      FSelected := False;
   end; // if
end; // MouseUp //
```

The exception occurs in procedure Button_Up in `FOnSelect (Sender);`. The exception is handled via a try..finally in order to reset the mouse pointer. I do not know how to reset the 'pressed' state, it is not the 'Down' state as I tried above. I could not reproduce this behavior in a small test program. I use Delphi XE.

What should I do to reset this button automatically to its unpressed state?

Comment: I don't see you doing anything with the "down" state in the code above. FSelected is a field of the TVector_Choice form that owns the button, but that obviously has no effect on the button. Besides that, why aren't you just handling the OnClick event like everyone else? And why are you emptying the message queue whenever the mouse button is released?

Comment: What's that `Application.ProcessMessages` for? That looks like it could give you some grief.

Comment: I added the ProcessMessages to be sure all messages were processed. It did not effect the behavior.

Comment: @Rob, You are right with the OnClick, just tested it, but the behavior remains. It just contains the statement `if Assigned (FOnSelect) then FOnSelect (Sender);`

Comment: Why? Just assign your selection method directly to the button's OnClick event. I don't understand why you've written any code at all.

Comment: Calling Application.ProcessMessages in an event handler for a queued message is categorically a bad idea. If there happens to be another mouse down message in the queue it will be processed! Pumping the message queue from your message pump will mix up the order of your queued messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code

In order to be able to set the down state on a single speedbutton you need to set
**A**: `AllowAllUp:= true` and
**B**: `groupindex <> 0`.
Only then can will the **C**: `down` property allow itself to be used as a checkbox would.

[image]

When those conditions are met, you can just use the OnClick event of a plain vanilla TSpeedButton.

```
procedure TForm2.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case btn2.Down of
    true: //do stuff when down
    false: //do stuff when up
  end; {case}
end;
```

No need for complicated custom message handling.

If `AllowAllUp:= false` then 2 or more speedbuttons with the same owner and the same `groupindex` act in unison like a group of radiobuttons.

**Notes on your code**
Finally your code seems to use a custom control inherited from TSpeedButton, but there's no `inherited` keyword in sight, how do you expect the button to operate when you disable the inherited behavior?

Apart from that point your code has many other issues, but the main issue is that if you **must** inherit from a standard control, because you need some special behavior, make sure you reuse as much behavior as possible and try and always call `inherited` in any code you override *(unless you want to completely disable inherited behavior)*

Comment: It is a custom control, sorry for not mentioning this important information. This is the correct answer with one vital addition: down should be set to false. The final code is this: `try
      if Assigned (FOnSelect)
         then FOnSelect (Sender);
   finally
      (Sender as TVector_Button).Down := False;
   end;` Johan pointed out that I had overlooked to set some important properties. Thank you all for your suggestions and help!

Comment: +1 Nice write up of how to achieve checkbox/radiobutton behaviour with speedbuttons.

Answer (score 2):

An exception isn't handled with a `try..finally`, you'll need to handle it with a `try..except`.

When an error is raised, and it's not handled (with try..except), the method aborts.

To do both a try..finally and try..except, you can nest them:

```
try
  // Do the thing that needs cleaning up
  try
    // Possible error raising code
  except
    // Handle the error here
  end;
finally
  // Cleanup
end;
```

Comment: You are compoletely right. I just made the remark to to have the people some idea what was happening with the exception. Not much. Alas this does not solve my problem :-)

Comment: Remember, if your exception handler is for special cleanup in the case of an exception, and not for actually handling the exception, it needs to end with a **raise;** statement so it doesn't swallow the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I **do** forget sometimes to use the `raise` again :-)